# C# DropDownList behaving strangely only on server, not local

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, server-side

I have a form with some text input fields and 3 comboboxes, and a submit button, which is intended to save the data of the form into a table on a database. So when I click the submit button, after some debugging, I found out that at the moment of clicking it, there is no selected value for the comboboxes, thus bringing up errors and exceptions, and obviously not saving the data into the DB. BUT not only that, in addition, after the submit button is clicked, the comboboxes lose all of their values and the complete list that filled them dissappears, as if they were not initialized.

The sad part of all this (since I'm aware I could just review my code some more) is that when I do exactly the same, with the exact same code (same dll's and everything) on my ASP.NET Visual Studio server (on my local machine) everything works perfect, hence I'm writting into the same remote database, and after clicking the submit button the data saves into the DB, and the form stays normal with all comboboxes as they were before clicking.

Why does this happen only on the server? Why can it write and read from the database with no problem at all on local?

I think it could be related to the PostBack on my Page_Load method (I initialize the comboboxes at it, but only if it is NOT a PostBack)... So could this be an issue related to how does the IIS server work with PostBacks which might be different than the local ASP.NET server?

**EDIT**
I am adding the HTML code of the form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    

<div class="popup" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 600px;">
    <table style="height: 148px; width: 584px">
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <abbr title="El N° de Folio le será otorgado luego de haber guardado la necesidad."><asp:Label ID="Labe" runat="server" Text="Folio *" class="innerControl"></asp:Label></abbr>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <abbr title="El N° de Folio le será otorgado luego de haber guardado la necesidad."><asp:TextBox ID="folTB" runat="server" Width="70px" class="innerControl" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox></abbr>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Fecha" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="fecTB" runat="server" Width="100px" class="innerControl" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender  ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="fecTB" DefaultView="Years" PopupButtonID="calBTN"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" runat="server" 
                                FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars="-" TargetControlID="fecTB">
                                </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
                                EnableScriptGlobalization="True">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Beneficiarios" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;" colspan="2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="benTB" runat="server" class="innerControl" Width="70px" Text="0" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender3" runat="server" 
                                FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="benTB">
                            </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Intendencia" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="intDDL" runat="server" class="innerControl" Width="270px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Mes / Año" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="mesDDL" runat="server" class="innerControl">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        /
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="anoDDL" runat="server" class="innerControl">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="_________" class="innerControl" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Meses" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="mesesTB" runat="server" Width="77px" class="innerControl" 
                                Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="TBExtender" runat="server" 
                                FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="mesesTB">
                            </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                        
                </table>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<br />
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Características del Requerimiento:" class="popup"></asp:Label>

<br />
<div class="popup" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 600px;">
    <table style="height: 100px; width: 584px">
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Población:" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="pobTB" runat="server" Width="70px" class="innerControl"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>                            
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Fundamentación:" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="3">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="fundTB" runat="server" Width="221px" class="innerControl" 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="7" Columns="35"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Tasa Desempleo:" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="empTB" runat="server" class="innerControl" Width="70px" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server" 
                                FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars=".," TargetControlID="empTB">
                                </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>                                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            %
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Tasa Pobreza:" class="innerControl"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="pobrTB" runat="server" class="innerControl" Width="70px" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender4" runat="server" 
                                FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars=".," TargetControlID="pobrTB">
                                </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            %
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="popup" style="width: 601px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="6" class="style2">
                <asp:Button ID="guardarNecesBTN" Text="Guardar" style="width: 110px;" 
                    runat="server" onclick="guardarNecesBTN_Click" Visible="true"/>
                <asp:Button ID="cerrarModBTN" Text="Cerrar" style="width: 110px;" 
                    runat="server" onclick="closePopUp" Visible="false"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="Test" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the .cs codebehind

```
public partial class nueva_necesidad : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int fol = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadMeses();
            loadAnos();
            loadIntendencias();
            String fec = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
            fec = fec + "-" + DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
            fec = fec + "-" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
            fecTB.Text = (fec);
        }
    }        

    protected void loadIntendencias()
    //Loads the intDDL with values taken from a DB table
    {
        intDDL.Items.Clear();
        ListItem newItem = null;

        List<entIntendencia> intList = new List<entIntendencia>();

        intList = boNeces.loadIntendencias(Convert.ToInt32(Session["reg_usu"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(Session["niv_usu"].ToString()));

        foreach (entIntendencia i in intList)
        {
            newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = i.nombre;
            newItem.Value = i.id_int.ToString();
            intDDL.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }

    protected void loadMeses()
    //Loads the mesDDL, pre-selecting the (current month + 2) from the DDL
    {
        DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
        int mesNum = d.Month;
        ListItem newItem = null;

        List<String> meses = new List<String>();
        meses.Add("Enero");
        meses.Add("Febrero");
        meses.Add("Marzo");
        meses.Add("Abril");
        meses.Add("Mayo");
        meses.Add("Junio");
        meses.Add("Julio");
        meses.Add("Agosto");
        meses.Add("Septiembre");
        meses.Add("Octubre");
        meses.Add("Noviembre");
        meses.Add("Diciembre");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = meses[i];
            newItem.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
            mesDDL.Items.Add(newItem);
        }

        if (d.Month != 11 && d.Month != 12)
            mesDDL.SelectedIndex = mesNum + 1;
        else
        {
            if (d.Month == 11)
                mesDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
            else
                mesDDL.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }   
    }

    protected void loadAnos()
    //Loads the anoDDL with a list of two: the current year and the next one.
    {
        anoDDL.Items.Clear();
        DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
        int ano = d.Year;
        ListItem newItem = null;

        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        list.Add(ano);
        list.Add(ano + 1);

        foreach (int an in list)
        {
            newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = an.ToString();
            newItem.Value = an.ToString();
            anoDDL.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }

    protected bool validaNecesidad(out int inten, out int meses, out int mes, out int ano, out int pob)
    //Validates the completion of the form's input fields.
    {
        inten = 0;
        meses = 0;
        mes = 0;
        ano = 0;
        pob = 0;

        Test.Text = intDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() + mesesTB.Text; //This line is intended to load the values of one of the comboboxes and one of the input textboxes onto a label called "Test" that's on the form itself, to check if they do have values or not, this is the first instruction that executes when the save button is clicked.

        if (!Int32.TryParse(intDDL.SelectedValue.ToString(), out inten))
        {
            Test.Text =  Test.Text + "Error en DDL intendencia";
            return false;
        }   
        if (inten <= 0)
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en DDL intendencia";
            return false;
        }

        if (!Int32.TryParse(mesesTB.Text, out meses))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB meses";
            return false;
        }
        if (meses <= 0)
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB meses";
            return false;
        }

        if (!Int32.TryParse(mesDDL.SelectedValue, out mes))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en DLL mes";
            return false;
        }
        if (mes <= 0)
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en DLL mes";
            return false;
        }

        if (!Int32.TryParse(anoDDL.SelectedValue, out ano))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en DLL ano";
            return false;
        }
        if (ano <= 0)
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en DLL ano";
            return false;
        }

        if (!Int32.TryParse(pobTB.Text, out pob))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB pob";
            return false;
        }
        if (pob <= 0)
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB pob";
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(empTB.Text))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB emp";
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pobrTB.Text))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB pobr";
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fundTB.Text))
        {
            Test.Text = Test.Text + "Error en TB fund";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void guardarNecesBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //Saves a new record on the NECESIDADES table.
    {
        int res = 0;            

        int inten = 0;
        int meses = 0;
        int mes = 0;
        int ano = 0;
        int pob = 0;

        if (validaNecesidad(out inten, out meses, out mes, out ano, out pob))
        {
            res = boNeces.saveNeces(inten, meses, mes, ano, pob, empTB.Text, pobrTB.Text, fundTB.Text, Session["log_usu"].ToString());
            if (res != 0)
            {
                Test.Text = Test.Text + "Folio creado correctamente con el N° " + res + ".";
                Test.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                guardarNecesBTN.Visible = false;
                cerrarModBTN.Visible = true;
                intDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
                loadMeses(); loadAnos();
                empTB.Text = ""; pobTB.Text = ""; pobrTB.Text = ""; fundTB.Text = "";                    
            }
            else
            {
                Test.Text = "Ha ocurrido un problema, favor intentar más tarde.";
                Test.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                guardarNecesBTN.Visible = false;
                cerrarModBTN.Visible = true;
                intDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
                loadMeses(); loadAnos();
                empTB.Text = ""; pobTB.Text = ""; pobrTB.Text = ""; fundTB.Text = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Test.Text =  Test.Text + "Faltan campos por completar.";
            Test.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }

    protected void closePopUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //Function used to call the JavaScript function that closes the modal popup.
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "closeMod", "closeMod();", true);
    }
}
```

**FINAL EDIT:**
I've already solved the issue. It was because of the enable view state property set to false on the application's configuration under IIS manager. Changed it to true and now it works same as local.

Comment: please post some code - show us your front-end code and .cs file code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add clearing of *mesDDL* dropdown in *loadMeses()* function.
Secondly, where is your sql-query? I didn't find that.

Comment: your answer should've been a comment. intDDL is the only ddl that loads from a DB table, and it does so on the line `intList = boNeces.loadIntendencias(Convert.ToInt32(Session["reg_usu"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(Session["niv_usu"].ToString()));` the "loadIntendencias()" method from the business layer calls another method from the data layer which has the querys. Do you suggest that I post that code too?

Comment: @glenLambert yes, I think so